# Logic App Not Receiving Messages

Tags: azure, iot, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub

I posted this question a couple of days ago [SMS Messaging from Azure IOT Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505441/sms-messaging-from-azure-iot-hub)

I have attempted to implement the logic app that had been suggested, my problem is no messages are being received by logic app through the service bus, in fact no messages are reaching the service bus. When I try to run the trigger in the logic app it gives me a pop-up saying "When_a_message_is_received_in_a_queue". When I run the logic app it says the work flow has timed out after a couple of minute.

I copied what this guy done except when he sends the emails I added a twilio connector.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-monitoring-notifications-with-azure-logic-apps

The messages that I am sending from my device to my IOT hub are being received by stream analytics, is it possible that stream analytics is stopping the messages from being fed to the service bus? The input to stream analytics is a data stream.

Thanks for any help and sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the message are indeed reaching your Service Bus queue by using tools like [Service Bus Explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available/). That would help narrow down the problem to either IoTHub -> ASA pipeline -> Service Bus pipeline or Service Bus -> Logic App.

Comment: No I check for this yesterday and the messages are not entering the service bus. Where could the problem since this is the case?

Comment: @crazyeyes Did you check the messages via Stream Analytics query?

Comment: No I haven't. How do I do this?